# Ant foreach avoiding empty variables

Tags: java, ant

I have the following line in the `build.xml` file:

```
<foreach list="${clients}" delimiter="," target="clean other hosts" param="client.string"/>
```

However, even if the `${clients}` is empty (it contains maybe a new-line character, because it is read from a file), it calls the target once.

Is there a workaround, to prevent this to happen (the calling of the loop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the task is correct, because `"".split(",")` equals `{""}`. But you can work around this problem by wrapping your task with an [`<if>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html):

Untested:

```
<if>
 <not><equals arg1="${clients}" arg2="" /></not>
 <then>
   <foreach list="${clients}" delimiter=","
            target="clean other hosts" param="client.string"/>
 </then>
</if>
```